# How can I calculate prediction error rate in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, probit

Can anybody lead me with a small simulation? Should I calculate prediction error rate from a classification table while splitting the data into two parts then fitting on the training data and predicting on the test data and see the misclassification (i.e. how many 1 predicted as 0 and 0 as 1, calculating the rate of misclassification).

I tried the following R code:

```
# prediction error rate for logit and probit for different sample sizes and sigma:

mu <- rep(0,4)   
library(MASS)  
pred.err <- function(sam.size,sigma,cut.point.latent){
  d <- mvrnorm(sam.size,mu,sigma)
  obs <- ifelse(d[ ,1]>cut.point.latent,1,0) # cut point for y*(latent) to be y(observed)
  x1 <- d[ ,2]
  x2 <- d[ ,3]
  x3 <- d[ ,4]
  dat <- data.frame(obs,x1,x2,x3)
  sam.select <- sample(1:nrow(dat),size=nrow(dat)*0.6) # 60% training data
  train.dat <- dat[sam.select,]    
  test.dat <- dat[-sam.select,]
  fit.logit.train <- with(train.dat,glm(obs ~ x1+x2+x3,family=binomial(link="logit")))
  fit.probit.train <- with(train.dat,glm(obs ~ x1+x2+x3,family=binomial(link="probit")))
  test.covar <- test.dat[ ,2:4]
  pred.prob.logit <-predict(fit.logit.train,newdata=test.covar,type="response")      
  pred.prob.probit <-predict(fit.probit.train,newdata=test.covar,type="response")
  obs.res <- test.dat[ , 1]
  cut.point.prob <- pnorm(cut.point.latent) # as cut point should be same for logit and probit
  pred.res.logit <- ifelse(pred.prob.logit >= cut.point.prob,1,0)
  pred.res.probit <- ifelse(pred.prob.probit >= cut.point.prob,1,0)
  logit.obs.pred <- data.frame(obs.res,pred.res.logit) # as in pred.res the columns 
  #are different from obs.res
  probit.obs.pred <- data.frame(obs.res, pred.res.probit)
  tab.logit <- table(logit.obs.pred)   
  tab.probit <- table(probit.obs.pred) 
  logit.pred.err.rate <- sum(tab.logit[1,2]+tab[2,1])/sum(tab.logit)
  probit.pred.err.rate <- sum(tab.probit[1,2]+tab[2,1])/sum(tab.probit)
  list(logit.pred.err.rate,probit.pred.err.rate) 
}

pred.err.logit <-NULL
pred.err.probit <-NULL
result <- function(rep.no,sam.size,sigma,cut.point.latent){
  for(i in 1:rep.no){
    sam <-pred.err(sam.size,sigma,cut.point.latent)
    pred.err.logit[i] <- sam[[1]]        
    pred.err.probit[i] <- sam[[2]]
  }      
  list(pred.err.logit,pred.err.probit)      
}

sigma.high <-matrix(c(1,.41,.5,-.7,.41,1,0,0,.5,0,1,0,-.7,0,0,1),nrow=4)     
output <- result(rep.no=1000,sam.size=500,sigma=sigma.high,cut.point.latent=.53)

### findings :     
t.test(output[[1]],output[[2]])
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a holdout data set. Also nothing wrong with cross-validation, which will also give you confidence intervals.

Comment: thank Marx, for your comment. can you tell me how cv.glm works ie. for 2 fold cross validation what is the underlying logic?

Comment: The general idea is that your training data set is a random sample. So, if you train many different versions of your model based on limited samples from the data you have on hand, and then evaluate each of these models based on the data it wasn't trained on, you will get a slightly different prediction error for each model. You can then take inferences from the set of prediction errors produced by these models. By evaluating the mean and variance of the set of prediction errors, you can extrapolate that your model will behave similarly when trained on all the available data.

Comment: You should read this WP article about CV. Also, you are better off with more folds than 2. I believe the general default is 10 folds. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29

Comment: The proportion classified correctly is mainly noise - the lowest precision accuracy score you could possibly have.  I would avoid it at all costs.  Look at the R `rms` package `lrm` function for a variety of useful, higher-precision indexes.

Comment: Look at some of the [many posts on calibration of LR models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logist*+regre*+calib*++answers%3A1) and also do not use accuracy, use s proper score function: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359909/is-accuracy-an-improper-scoring-rule-in-a-binary-classification-setting